# How to show large icons when using axSymbologyControl?

Tags: c#, symbols, esri

I'm using ArcGIS axSymbologyControl. How to show large icons?

```
public IStyleGalleryItem GetItem()
{
    m_styleGalleryItem = null;
    axSymbologyControl1.StyleClass = esriSymbologyStyleClass.esriStyleClassScaleBars;

    this.ShowDialog()
    return m_styleGalleryItem;
}
```

my desktop application
[image]

ArcGis window

[image]

Comment: what is the question? what is the problem? what is the error message? [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The current version of ArcGis 10

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `Size` property that you can set? Something like

```
public IStyleGalleryItem GetItem()
{
    m_styleGalleryItem = null;
    axSymbologyControl1.StyleClass = esriSymbologyStyleClass.esriStyleClassScaleBars;

    //try different x and y values here for various sizes
    axSymbologyControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 264);

    this.ShowDialog()
    return m_styleGalleryItem;
}
```

I have no experience with the ESRI/ArcGIS libraries, but controls deriving from [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size(v=vs.110).aspx) have this property, and this *seems* similar.

I found some sample code buried in the [ArcObjects SDK 10 .NET API Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004800000075000000), where I pulled that line above from. Not sure if that is the exact library you are using, but perhaps those docs will provide better information than I.

Comment: This property changes the size of contol. Need to change the size of Items.